# How do I Calculate the coords of a Point on a non-circular arc

Tags: android, math, graphics, paint

I'm trying to draw what looks like an old Analog meter.  So I have an Arc (that may NOT be circular) drawn using the canvas.drawArc() method.
I need to be able to add "tick" marks (perpendicular to the arc) on the arc every X degrees.

So I want to find the coordinates of the end points of the tick mark line.

Anyone know the math needed for that?

Comment: you can use formula of ellipse: (x^2)/(a^2) + (y^2)/(b^2) = 1

Comment: Not sure how I would apply that.  Say the arc is drawn from 0 deg to 180 deg.  I want to find the points for a line that crosses the arc at 10 degrees (20, 30, etc..).
As far as I can tell, the formula you gave just gives me the X if I know the Y (or Y if I know the X).

Comment: hey you will have to do a little math. All i can help you with are formulae and links 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22064/calculating-a-point-that-lies-on-an-ellipse-given-an-angle

Comment: The point was that I don't know the math.
Anyway, it looks like the 2nd answer in the link you gave does have the answer I need, now I just need to find a way to translate it into something I can understand.  I've never seen that notation language before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use parametric ellipse equations:

```
x = x0 + rx * cos(a)
y = y0 + ry * sin(a)
```

- x0,y0 is ellipse center
- rx,ry are half axises
- a is angle

Comment: And that is definitely easier to understand.  Thanks.